# Select Sql Query returns ceiling Exponential value for big integer

Tags: c#, sql-server, biginteger, typeconverter, exponentiation

I do have one field in sql table which contains Big Integer typed records,
Now in my c# script when I fire select query on this table, it returns Exponential value instead of numeric value in DataTable

I converted it by 
 
`double.parse(expVal)` 
 and also tried 
`double.parse(exoVal, NumberFormat.float/any/allowExponent)`

well it converted number from Exponential format to numeric format but it did not solve my problem.

As record in database was like : 904187**576**

and after select query I got in DataTable : 9.04187**6**E+08

as Exponential value was ceiling and not specifying full 9 digits

after converting I got : 904187**600** instead of 904187**576**

So what should I do?? what type should I use for conversion??

Comment: and one more thing, I m not specifying any DataTable related rules or columns name or data type, DataTable is being created automatically

Comment: Please would you post the C# code you use to get the value into your DataTable?

Comment: `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`                                                    `DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();` `mySqlCommand.CommandText = "select <value> from <table>";`
`mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "DailyData");`
`dataTable = ds.Tables["DailyData"];`

Comment: have you tried `int.parse(expVal)`?

Comment: well yes,.. I tried all what blinked in my mind.. `int.parse(expVal)`, `long.parse(expVal)`, float, double, even tried                                            `decimal.parse(long.parse(expVal).ToString())` .. one more thing I noticed, In my DataTable `dataTable` I seen that data type of that field is System.Single, is it okay for big int?? becase there is another field of Float type and for it also my dataTable in script is showing System.Single !!!.. Thanks